# Не работает пример из книги Лутца Программирование на Python том 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

Изучаю применение Python по книге Лутца и при запуске примера из книги столкнулся с проблемой: HTTP-сервер не выполнил мой сценарий, а браузер выдал ошибку:

> Error response
>
> Error code: 403
>
> Message: CGI script is not executable ('/cgi-bin/tutor0.py').
>
> Error code explanation: 403 - Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.

Вот код сервера:

```
import os, sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
webdir = '.'
port = 80

if len(sys.argv) > 1: webdir = sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) > 2: port = int(sys.argv[2])
print('webdir "%s", port %s' % (webdir, port) )

os.chdir(webdir)
srvraddr = ('', port)
srvrobj = HTTPServer(srvraddr, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvrobj.serve_forever()
```

Вот код сценария:(tutor0.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print("<HTML>")
print("<HEAD>")
print("<TITLE>example</TITLE>")
print("</HEAD>")
print("<BODY>")
print("<H1>Hello world!</H1>")
print("</BODY>")
print("<HTML>")
```

Сначала я запускаю веб-сервер от имени root (команда `sudo`), затем (при выполняющемся сервере) в браузере перехожу по адресу http://localhost/cgi-bin/tutor0.py
И вместо страницы, которую должен был сгенерировать мой сценарий Python, получаю ошибку, которую описал вначале: `Message: CGI script is not executable`.

Comment: А запущенный руками из shell этот tutor0.py выполняется?

Comment: Да, выполняется. Печатает разметку HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё заработало после команды:

```
chmod +x tutor0.py
```